# SSE unsigned/signed subtraction of 16 bit register

Tags: c, performance, sse

I have a __m128i register (Vector A) with 16 bit values with the content:

```
{100,26,26,26,26,26,26,100} // A Vector
```

Now I subtract the vector

```
{82,82,82,82,82,82,82,82}
```

With the instruction

```
_mm_sub_epi16(a_vec,_mm_set1_epi16(82))
```

The expected result should be the following vector

```
{18,-56,-56,-56,-56,-56,-56,18}
```

But I get

```
{18,65480,65480,65480,65480,65480,65480,18}
```

How can I solve that the vector is treated as signed?

The A Vector was created by this instruction:

```
__m128i a_vec = _mm_srli_epi16(_mm_unpacklo_epi8(score_vec_8bit, score_vec_8bit), 8)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`65480` is the same value as `-56` (they are both `0xffc8` at the register level) - you're just *displaying* it as if it were an unsigned short.

Note that for non-saturating addition and subtraction of binary values without carry/borrow flags it really is irrelevant whether the values are signed or unsigned - hence the same instruction can be used for adding both signed and unsigned shorts - the only difference is how you subsequently interpret (or display) the result.